How did G. I. Taylor derive the PDE's in his landmark 1941 paper?
To gain a deeper understanding of the derivation of G. I. Taylor's foundational equation $R= S(γ)t^\frac{2} {5} E^\frac{1}{5} ρ_0^\frac{-1}{5} $, I'd be grateful if you could point me towards the specific derivations of the three partial differential equations presented as equations (4), (8), and (10) in his paper "The formation of a blast wave by a very intense explosion I. Theoretical discussion":


lEqn. 8 is the conservation of mass equation in spherical coordinates.  Eqn. 10 is the  equation for conservation of entropy for an ideal gas experiencing radial and time variations (axially and longitudinally symmetric).  Eqn. 4 describes conservation of momentum (Newtons 2nd law).

The equations are not explicitly referenced, and I would be grateful if you could point me towards the relevant literature for further understanding.

Transport Phenomena by Bird et Al

Bird et. al was published in 2002, some 60 years after Taylor's 1941 paper, so may well be derivative. I was hoping for an explanation that predates Taylor's work in order to understand his  argument.

it'll be iii there.

I couldn’t find any of Taylor’s three equations, or their derivations in Bird et al. Do you have a contemporaneous reference?

These three equations are the basic Navier Stokes equations of fluid mechanics. You can find them in any treaty about fluid mechanics, or online.

Could you provide me with your best reference please?

The equations are not explicitly referenced, and I would be grateful if you could point me towards the relevant literature for further understanding.
